# How to plot different colour for negative datapoint in line chart c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datapoint

I want to create line chart by datagridview I need red colour plot line for negative values and green for positive values. I write the code but I get only green colour for all data points.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvReport.Rows)
{ 
    decimal val = 0;
    val = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[8].Value.ToString());

    if (val < 0)
    {
        Dchart.Series[0].Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }

    if (val > 0)
    {
        Dchart.Series[0].Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    }

    Dchart.Series[0].Points.AddXY(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString(), row.Cells[8].Value.ToString());
    Dchart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 3;
}
```

Comment: What is `Dchart`? Are you sure you *have* data with value < 0

Comment: yes data with values <0 & Dchart is name of the chart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to color each `DataPoint` individually:

```
int index = Dchart.Series[0].Points.AddXY(row.Cells[0].Value,
                                          row.Cells[8].Value);
DataPoint newPoint = Dchart.Series[0].Points[index];
newPoint.Color = newPoint.YValues[0] < 0 ? Color.Red : Color.Green;
```

Note that the color goes into only one line!

Also note that your conversion orgy isn't really needed..

Final note: You are adding all your values as `strings`. This is a serious mistake! Doing so will **lose** all x-values and result in an uncontrolled default conversion of the y-values.

**Always** add **all** values as numbers or `DateTimes`!!

If you find that you need to convert the cell value `objects` to numbers do so and create the `DataPoint` as a whole, best including the Color before adding it with `series.Add()`!

Comment: got error cannot implicitly convert bool to Drawing.color

Comment: You probably meant `newPoint.Color = newPoint.YValues[0] < 0 ? Color.Red : Color.Green;`